# Rate On App Store (In-App) Method - Error : "Your request produced an error. [newNullLineResponse]". Re New App To Be Submitted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store

I'm about to submit my new app to the App Store. I found this thread that seems to be the most current in terms of the correct syntax to use re the method required to execute a "Rate This App" process : [How can I add a link for a rate button with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755069/how-can-i-add-a-link-for-a-rate-button-with-swift) (March, 2015)

I have a button in my app that allows the user to leave a review on the App Store - within my app. Not via external browser.

My code as follows:

```
@IBAction func RateUs(sender: AnyObject) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(123456789)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1)")!);
}
```

My `app id` I have listed as a numeric only format - listed above as `123456789` for example purposes.

I run the build on my iPhone as simulator. No errors and it builds 100% OK.

When I press execute the IBAction (i.e. press button) to leave a review, the App Store window appears, starts to load and I get this error on a blank screen:

"Your request produced an error.
 [newNullLineResponse]"

Three (3) questions:

1. Is my above code up-to-date and correct?
2. Is this error standard as I my app is not yet on the App Store? and
3. My app is available Worldwide, does the method I use above cater for all App Stores by region?

I am presuming this error is expected.

I would just like to confirm 1,2 and 3 above.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue today. Tried other ways and came up with this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id1085881746")!);
```

My app is not released yet so it just gives me a screen in app store saying this app is not yet available in this country. This works fine it just cant open the review tab programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried this?   `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(1111222233)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software)")!);`
} ..... `1111222233` is example app ID.

Comment: Pls see this related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519537/in-app-link-to-rate-an-app?noredirect=1#comment58733722_35519537