# In App Link To Rate An App

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, rate

I realise this has been a heavy traffic question over the past few years.

I have looked at every question and answer, and every comment and re-comment. Answers and comments are wide in range. Apple are famous for changing the landscape continuously.

I would just like the most updated method to allow the user to rate my app via a button in-app.

This is what I have as the most updated version:

```
@IBAction func RateUs(sender: AnyObject) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(111222333)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1)")!);
}
```

where `111222333` is my app ID.

Is this correct? I am about to submit my app for review and need to use what is currently accepted by Apple. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Possible modification to:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?‌​type=Purple+Software&id=\(111222333)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrde‌​ring=1)")!);
```

incorporating: `type=Purple+Software` (as per kind suggestion in comment below).

Or perhaps I should try:

```
func jumpToAppStore(appId: String) {
let url = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appId)"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
```

}

as per an accepted answer here : [App store link for "rate/review this app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app) dated Aug 20, 2015.

Comment: I believed you already checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124080/app-store-link-for-rate-review-this-app?rq=1 .I think you url is missing the `type=Purple+Software` part.

Comment: Re this comment in that thread? _Note - the "type=Purple+Software" has to be there and it has to be literally "Purple Software" - it's not the name of your company, it's a codename for iPhone applications :) I wasted an hour before I figured this out... – Kuba Suder Oct 24 '11 at 11:27_ .... do we think that this is still relevant? I guess if so, I will have to amend my above code to allow for both pre and post iOS7 (and iOS7) devices?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried myself. The `"type=Purple+Software"` is actually crucial. Without it the link won't work.

Comment: I uploaded a new app about a week ago. So this is still relevant. At least for now.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS8+. I don't really know how the link behaves on iOS7 device and below. But I think it should also work, since that answer providing the link is over 6 years old.

Comment: So I should be using: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=\(111222333)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1)")!);`  for it to actually function?

Comment: I believe so, as long as the `id=` part is OK.

Comment: `func jumpToAppStore(appId: String) {
    let url = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appId)"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
}` could also be a possible solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104019/discussion-between-paul-satem-and-skyline75489).

Comment: I haven't really tested on that one yet.

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(1081797746)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software)")!);` ..... Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 3):

After additional searches, re-searches and helpful comments, I have amended my code to:

```
@IBAction func RateUs(sender: AnyObject) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(1081797746)&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software)")!);
}
```