# Is it possible to request app rating in an WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, applescript, rating

I have an app running WKWebView on a local html file, and I would like to add the function request app rating, but I don't know if it is possible and how to call that. The project runs in a XCode 13 on swift.

Comment: No,  you need to make that call from native code

Comment: You can still do it but trigger it natively after a certain time. Like 1 min after the app has launched, or something like that (I'm using the most simple example).  This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155499/5024088


If you want to trigger the app rating from WebView, then that would be tricky. You need to implement JS function in the HTML file, then handle the response in Swift (once you handle the response of the JS function, you can trigger it natively as on the link above).

Please specify clearly from where you want to trigger the app rating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to register a `WKUserContentController` on your `WKWebView` like this

```swift
let webView = WKWebView()
let storeKitHandler = StoreKitHandler()
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(storeKitHandler, name: "storeKitHandler")
```

Where the `StoreKitHandler` is a class conforming to `WKScriptMessageHandler`

```swift
class MyHandler: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "callback" {
            if let body = message.body as? String, body == "requestReview" {
                SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then call the method like this from JavaScript

```js
window.webkit.messageHandlers.storeKitHandler.postMessage('requestReview');
```

This will then call `userContentController(_:WKUserContentController, didReceive: WKScriptMessage)` with the message name `storeKitHandler` and body `requestReview`.